# cmakelists.txt - combine with existing Makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Im new to **CMakeLists.txt** and it's syntax so Im hoping this is pretty easy.

Project has two subdirectories: A and B

A requires files from B

B has a **CMakeLists.txt** already.
A just has a **Makefile**.
A doesn't build an executable; just a .o for another separate project(this folder is part of a larger build).

Ive create a **CMakeLists.txt** in the parent folder but I can't figure out how to call the **make** in folder A.

### parent CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2.3)
project(PARSER)

add_subdirectory(B)

add_custom_target(a-sub
   COMMAND "make"
   WORKING_DIRECTORY "./A")
```

When I build this it runs the make in folder B but does nothing to folder A.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

---

Initially I tried to rewrite the existing (folder A) **Makefile** into a **CMakeLists.txt** but didn't get v far. This syntax is a bit tricky.

Comment: You forget *ALL* options for add_custom_target, so it will be processed by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mixing make and cmake is a good idea. If you can't convert A to use cmake then I'd suggest making A and separate projects. Use cmake for B and install the headers and the libraries somewhere. Then use a makefile for A and point it to where B is installed.